# Forwarding animation on ToggleClass

Tags: jquery, css, animation, menu

I´m trying to display a fullscreen menu with toggleClass animated with jquery. I´m able to do it, but I would like to to have the same effect forwardding the animation closing the menu. Any approach to this is welcome.

My codepen: https://codepen.io/carlos-turpin-trives/pen/jOweWBN

I am using a simple function that reveals the menu after an overlay appears in this way:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $('.overlay').toggleClass('open');
   $('h1 span').toggleClass('opens');  
  });
```

showing overlay with this code css:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background: #1abc9c;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index:50;
}
.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and the menu in this way:

```
.opens {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal 1.5s;
}
@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0,100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0,0);
  }
}
```

I would learn how to forward the animation with toggleClass. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved using transition-delay in each class that reveals content.